# Network packet analyzer for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a network packet analyzer like TCPDUMP for Windows Phone 7?
I want to monitor network activity of my WP7 phone while it is in idle mode o tack which application is using the WLAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fiddler to monitor traffic from your WP7 device. See this post for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/01/09/debugging-windows-phone-7-device-traffic-with-fiddler.aspx